# Graphviz -> svg (->pdf) text flows out of the box for some viewers

Tags: svg, graphviz

An svg file generated from graphviz looks fine in some viewers (Chrome, Gnome Image Viewer) but doesn't in others (Inkscape, when converting using ImageMagick to pdf).

Here's what my minimal example looks like, on the left is Chrome (correct rendering), on the right is Inkscape (wrong):

[image: minimal example]

The above was generated by this graphviz code:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=box];
    foo[label="long text long text long text"]
}
```

SVG produced by:
`dot g.txt -Tsvg -o g.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
 -->
<!-- Title: %3 Pages: 1 -->
<svg width="177pt" height="44pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 177.00 44.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 40)">
<title>%3</title>
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-40 173,-40 173,4 -4,4"/>
<!-- foo -->
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>foo</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="169,-36 0,-36 0,-0 169,-0 169,-36"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="84.5" y="-14.3" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">long text long text long text</text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

What is causing this? Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix it?
Thanks!

Program versions:

```
graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
Inkscape 0.92.2pre0 (973e216, 2017-07-25)
GNOME Image Viewer 3.26.2
Chrome Version 69.0.3497.92
ImageMagick 6.9.9-34 Q16 x86_64 2018012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Imagemagick 6.9.10.11 Q16 Mac OSX with inkscape @0.92.3_4, I get the following. Note I just convert to jpg to be able to post here. The pdf is the same.

```
convert test.svg test.pdf
convert test.pdf test.jpg
```

[image]

So I conclude it is either your Imagemagick version or more likely your version of Inkscape or a faulty install.

Comment: Did you use the svg file I provided, or did you generate it using graphviz? Also any idea what could be bad in the install - it seems strange that two independent programs (ImageMagick, Inkscape) have problems, unless they're likely using the same 'backend' for svg and for some reason others (Chrome, Gnome Image Viewer) are using a different one

Comment: I used your SVG code in your post here. I would suggest you first try upgrading Inkscape and see if that helps. I have no idea what those other programs use for rendering SVG. All I can say is that in my configuration of Imagemagick and my version of Inkscape, it works fine. Your Inkscape is `Inkscape 0.92.2pre0`. What does the `pre` mean? Is that like a beta or pre-release. The date is also over a year old. So again I suggest you upgrade Inkscape.

Comment: One other thought is that perhaps your issue might be with freetype. Perhaps Inkscape has a dependency on freetype when rendering text. What is your version of freetype? Mine is  2.7.1. The other thought might be that you do not have the needed font that your SVG file wants.

Comment: Thanks, all good suggestions, I'll check it out. Not sure what `pre` means, I'm using a custom ubuntu-based Linux distribution provided by my employer so not sure what they did there.